# Response Parsed Body Dynamic Value for json hash which has dots in keys

Tags: paw-app

When using Paw to parse JSON response bodies for subsequent requests, I ran into this response:

```
{
  "named_items": {
    "key.with.periods": "stuff stuff stuff",
    "key.with.more.periods": "stuff thing stuff"
  }
}
```

In javascript, this is straightforward to access with `[]` notation on the object: `response.named_items['key.with.periods']`, however I cannot get Paw to capture the value properly via right click "Copy as response body dynamic variable", or manual construction any way I can think of.

Is there a way around this limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, you can escape the dots with backslashes. In your case, this should work:

`key\.with\.periods`

*We will try to make this more obvious in the next release. Thanks!*

Comment: brilliant. I didn't see that happening when copying as a response value, which is where I would have expected it to do whatever it needed to make that happen. Anyway, thanks for the response and the great software!